# Styling specific <li> element in unordered list <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For example,
I have the following html:

```
<ul>
       <li>1</li>
       <li>2</li>
       <ul>
          <li>1</li>
           <ul>
               <li>1</li>
               <li>2</li>
           </ul>
           <li>2</li>
       </ul>
   </ul>
   <ul>
       <li>1</li>
       <li>2</li>
   </ul>
   <ul>`enter code here`
       <li>1</li>
       <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

And, i want to style only **li** elements which have **value = 1**.
I tried this in jQuery and it works , but i want to know if there is a better way to perfom this.

My approach:

```
$("ul li").each(
   function(){
       if($(this).text() == "1"){
           $(this).css("color","red");
       }
   });
```

Comment: <li data-value=1>1</li>, and than CSS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$("ul li:contains('1')").css("color","red");
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rM4LW/)

If you have `li` elements with other values than 1 or 2 you can use jquery [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$("ul li").filter(
    function(){
        return $(this).text() == 1;
    }).css("color","red");
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rM4LW/17/)

Comment: This would also match if the text was 10.

Comment: Yes I have values = "1" or "2" and it works .Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `css` method:

```
$('li').css('color', function(_, currentColor) {
    return $.trim(this.textContent) === '1' ? 'red' : null;
});
```

From jQuery [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function)'s documentation:

> Note: If nothing is returned in the setter function (ie. `function( index, style ){}` ), or if `undefined` is returned, the current value is not changed. This is useful for selectively setting values only when certain criteria are met.

Answer (score 2):

If you have only `1` and `2` you can use following

```
$("li:contains(1)").css("color","red");
```

It will include an `li` if the content is `21`.